# Scraping webrtc page in Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, webrtc

I am doing a WebRTC demo in Android, the code is simple starting an intent

```
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://apprtc.appspot.com"));
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

The browser opens up with the WebRTC demo, my question relates on how I can scrape back the ?r=ddddddd (where d is a digit). This number is important to pass on to the the other side in the webrtc call.

This number appears also in the url when the page opens up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access an URL neither the changes it suffers after it has been sent in the Intent.

But in this case, the demo apprtc generates an id, but it also accepts an id generated by you. So you can instead generate an id on your application, form the final url, and then send it in the intent and to the other user.

You can even add letters to the generated id, so you can create something that starts with something like your app name, just to be harder to match existing sessions.

NOTE: I must advise you that this is not a very good way to create applications as apprtc is only a demonstration, it is subject of frequent changes and you should not rely your service on others.